# stack multiple columns from different tables in sql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to stack pairs of columns I match together in sql. For example, I match entries in column A to column B from different tables, then I want to add column C and D to column A and B. It should look like:

```
A1 B1
A2 B2
C1 D1
C2 D2
```

Is there an easy way to do this? I can get columns ABCD into a table, but I don't know enough about sql syntax to insert one on top of the other. Insert into statements looked hopeful, here's some code I tried that doesn't work at all:

```
    SELECT
    col_A,
    col_B
    FROM
    table_A as a
    LEFT JOIN
    table_B as b on b.ID = a.ID;
    --this is where I think I'm messing up:
    INSERT INTO a
    col_C,
    col_D
    FROM
    table_c as c
    LEFT JOIN
    table_d as d on d.ID = c.ID
```

Any ideas? Easier way to do this? Thanks! (I need to use PostgreSQL if that changes anything)

Comment: can you add more details? 
I struggle to understand ..

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the data you are trying to append is of the same type, you can use a union all (union if you want to remove duplicates):

```
WITH table1 AS (
    SELECT
      col_A,
      col_B
   FROM table_A as a
   LEFT JOIN table_B as b 
     on b.ID = a.ID
   ),

    table2 AS (
    SELECT
      col_C,
      col_D
   FROM table_C as c
   LEFT JOIN table_D as d
      on c.ID = d.ID
    )

   SELECT *
   FROM table1
   union all
   SELECT * 
   FROM table2
  ;
```